# Cannot open text file using ifstream

Tags: c++

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("‪C:\\Users\\Zach\\Desktop\\input.txt");
if (!fin) 
{
    cout << "e";
}
```

e is printing whether I use the full pathway or just input.txt from a resource file

Comment: Does the file exist? An `ifstream` will not create a new file.

Comment: Yes; I copied the location from its properties on windows

Comment: You could try: `std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';`

Comment: @cchhhhhh00 Is `Zach` the user account that is running your app? If not, then is the user an admin? Only an admin can access files in another user's profile.

Comment: @Galik it is undefined whether  `ifstream` sets `errno` on error (if `errno` even exists - most C++ compilers on Windows don't). You might be thinking of `GetLastError()` instead (since `ifstream` will ultimately have to call `CreateFile()` internally)

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is mandatory for `POSIX` systems. I thought it was worth a try as I think even `Windows` has some `POSIX` conformance. It seems to work on on-line Windows compilers.

Comment: @Galik Windows is not a POSIX system, though it has a POSIX subsystem, but is not compliant and hasn't been for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists, make sure that you have got the path specified correctly. Since you're running on Windows, you can verify the full path to your executable with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096

std::string getExePath()
{
    char result[BUFSIZE];
    return std::string(result, GetModuleFileName(NULL, result, BUFSIZE));
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
        infile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open input.txt!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Executable path is ->" << getExePath() << "<-" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will allow you to verify that your path to the input file is correct, assuming that it's collocated with your executable.

Answer (score -2):

You need to direct output into the `ifstream` object by using `fin << "string";` and not directing to standard out via `cout`.

Comment: the file not opening is my issue

Comment: ìfstream`is an input, not an output.